# string matches regex pattern but return result is nil after extracting substring via range

Tags: ios, swift, regex, range

I have a regex pattern which a string matches. But on trying to extract the substring from that string, I get an empty value. Here's the code:

```
@objc public var attendeeAccesscode: String? {

    let pattern = ["(?<=X|\\*|\\/|,|,,|,,,)(\\s)?(\\d+(\\s|-)*)*"]
    let attributes = attributesToLookup()

        guard let regEx = RegEx.getRegularExpression(with: pattern, and: .caseInsensitive) else {
            continue
        }

        for string in attributes {

            if let string = string
            {
                let matches = regEx.matches(in: string, options: [], range: string.nsrange)

                for match in matches {

                    let rawString = string.nsstring.substring(with: match.range(at: 0))
                    return rawString

                }
            }
        }

    return nil
}
```

I am trying to test against this pattern string:

```
1-888-999-1010,, 123345666
```

The raw string itself is nil.
I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: Your code uses some unknown classes and properties. What are `RegEx`, `nsstring` and `nsrange` ? Even when I guessed them, your code does not compile. Your `pattern` is an Array of String, how do you make a regex with it? Why `continue` appears in non-loop context? And even if I fixed all of them by guess, the result was an empty String (`""`) not nil. You may have simplified your code too much. Please show a buildable code which reproduces your issue. Anyway, if all my guesses are right, you can try this pattern `"(?<=X|\\*|\\/|,|,,|,,,)(\\s)?(\\d+(\\s|-)*)+"`.

Comment: Yes. This worked. Thank you.